# Creating Access Apps in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, microsoft-access, access-services

I would like to find out more regarding creating Access App in SharePoint 2013 in term of:

- how far you can customize it?
- Security level. Is that using SharePoint security or other security?
- Do i need to have access to SQL back-end?
- What services required. Office Web apps or Access service or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**how far you can customize it?** I would say its depend upon the requirement and skills set you have.It is very much open ended.

**Security level. Is that using SharePoint security or other security?**
Get more control over who can modify your app. SharePoint now comes with three default permissions levels–Designer, Author, and Reader. Only Designers can make design changes to views and tables. Authors can change data but not the design, and Readers (you guessed it) can only read existing data.

**Do i need to have access to SQL back-end?** Access apps use SQL Server to provide the best performance and data integrity.

**What services required. Office Web apps or Access service or both?** Access Services in SharePoint Server 2013 are service applications that enable you to share two types of Access 2013 solutions on the web.Access apps & Access web databases are supported for backward compatibility. No Need of OWA.

Here are  few helpful resources:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/what-s-new-in-access-2013-HA102809500.aspx

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861519(v=office.15)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee861519%28v=office.15%29)